# Postgres batch insert order

Tags: postgresql

If I put a batch insert in postgres, I found the order in which insert statement were present does not get honoured in database. That is, suppose I have a table with three columns - value, timestamp and autoincrement column And if i am doing batch insert with insert statements with value from 1 to 1000 in order, then it is not guaranteed that after batch insert operation, 1000th value will have autoincrement value of 1000 as well and also the timestamp column value is also not guaranteed to be the latest.

Is there a way through configuration or settings anywhere that i can guarantee the order of insertion same as order of insert statements?

Comment: Please show us your existing code to make your question comprehensive.

Comment: PostgreSQL [cannot guarantee insertion order](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95822/does-postgres-preserve-insertion-order-of-records), and you should never rely on insertion order if it's relevant to you. Instead, you should specify whatever order you need in your queries.

Comment: Even if you could guarantee insertion order that would NOT ensure a later select would return them in that order. You must keep in mind that a table is "an order-less collection of tuples (rows)". As indicated by @vicpermir the **only way** to ensure a particular sequence is to specify "***Order By***" in the query.

Comment: Insertion order is not honored in database most probably because PostgreSQL is launching several parallel insert threads.